# Unable to remove members from a group in mesibo

Tags: node.js, kotlin, messaging, mesibo

I'm not able to remove members from a group in mesibo neither from the backend api (from node.js) nor from the mesibo playground.

I am working with the Mesibo backend apis. I used [this documentation](https://mesibo.com/documentation/api/backend-api/group-management/#create-a-group) to make the apis in node.js and used the [mesibo playground](https://mesibo.com/documentation/api/backend-api/playground/) for reference. But I'm not able to remove members from the group neither by using our backend api nor from the mesibo playground.

Though I'm getting response as true in playground, but users are not removing from the group.
Please look into this matter, I'm attaching the request and response below for the reference.

** Get Group Members Request**

```
{
  "op": "groupgetmembers",
  "group": {
    "gid": 2792783
  },
  "count": 20,
  "token": "app_token_sample"
}
```

** Get Group Member Response**

```
{
  "mcount": 6,
  "count": 6,
  "gid": 2792783,
  "members": [
    {
      "uid": 5826089,
      "address": "+918563919033",
      "permissions": {
        "send": true,
        "recv": true,
        "pub": true,
        "sub": true,
        "list": true
      }
    },
    {
      "uid": 5849285,
      "address": "+915555555555",
      "permissions": {
        "send": true,
        "recv": true,
        "pub": true,
        "sub": true,
        "list": true
      }
    },
    {
      "uid": 5855784,
      "address": "+919960885590",
      "permissions": {
        "send": true,
        "recv": true,
        "pub": true,
        "sub": true,
        "list": true
      }
    },
    {
      "uid": 5856718,
      "address": "+915454545454",
      "permissions": {
        "send": true,
        "recv": true,
        "pub": true,
        "sub": true,
        "list": true
      }
    },
    {
      "uid": 5856787,
      "address": "+919960147849",
      "permissions": {
        "send": true,
        "recv": true,
        "pub": true,
        "sub": true,
        "list": true
      }
    },
    {
      "uid": 5856798,
      "address": "+915252525252",
      "permissions": {
        "send": true,
        "recv": true,
        "pub": true,
        "sub": true,
        "list": true
      }
    }
  ],
  "op": "groupgetmembers",
  "result": true
}
```

** Remove Member Request**

```
{
  "op": "groupeditmembers",
  "group": {
    "gid": 2792783,
    "memebrs": {
      "remove": 1
    },
    "members": {
      "m": "+918563919033"
    }
  },
  "token": "app_token_sample"
}
```

**Response**

```
{
  "group": {
    "gid": 2792783
  },
  "op": "groupeditmembers",
  "result": true
}
```

** Get Group Members Request After Removing**

```
{
  "op": "groupgetmembers",
  "group": {
    "gid": 2792783
  },
  "count": 20,
  "token": "app_token_sample"
}
```

** Get Group Member Response**

```
{
  "mcount": 6,
  "count": 6,
  "gid": 2792783,
  "members": [
    {
      "uid": 5826089,
      "address": "+918563919033",
      "permissions": {
        "send": true,
        "recv": true,
        "pub": true,
        "sub": true,
        "list": true
      }
    },
    {
      "uid": 5849285,
      "address": "+915555555555",
      "permissions": {
        "send": true,
        "recv": true,
        "pub": true,
        "sub": true,
        "list": true
      }
    },
    {
      "uid": 5855784,
      "address": "+919960885590",
      "permissions": {
        "send": true,
        "recv": true,
        "pub": true,
        "sub": true,
        "list": true
      }
    },
    {
      "uid": 5856718,
      "address": "+915454545454",
      "permissions": {
        "send": true,
        "recv": true,
        "pub": true,
        "sub": true,
        "list": true
      }
    },
    {
      "uid": 5856787,
      "address": "+919960147849",
      "permissions": {
        "send": true,
        "recv": true,
        "pub": true,
        "sub": true,
        "list": true
      }
    },
    {
      "uid": 5856798,
      "address": "+915252525252",
      "permissions": {
        "send": true,
        "recv": true,
        "pub": true,
        "sub": true,
        "list": true
      }
    }
  ],
  "op": "groupgetmembers",
  "result": true
}
```

Comment: Please post complete output without masking any details. Also, post the output of `groupgetmembers` before and after the `groupeditmembers`. If the information is sensitive, send us a ticket.

Comment: I've edited the question description. Please check! @mesibo